# NavFn setting up cost array (costarr) from ROS's costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The `NavFn` planner takes in ROS's costmap created by `costmap_2d` package. The input is in the format mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Map_type_parameters).

Now, when `NavFn` reads those values, it refactors everything from the (0, 253) range by the equation `COST_NEUTRAL + COST_FACTOR * input_cost_value` which scales all of it proportionally to the (50, 253) range.

Why is this done?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197457/navfn-setting-up-cost-array-(costarr)-from-ros%27s-costmap/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-11-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that this was done to ensure there is always a minimal cost to visit a cell. Otherwise, if the costmap has 0-cost cells any path nevermind the length would be equally good as a solution.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-14**:
I see, but you could potentially resolve that by making the score 1. What is the need to scale the data to 50+?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-14**:
If my guess is even correct this is just a balancing factor. if there is a narrow passage with 253, you'd be willing to take a 253 times as long detour to avoid that.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-14**:
The author mentions something about narrow packages when deciding on the COST_FACTOR (set to 0.8) which is different from the initial 50 offset.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-14**:
I'm not sure I entirely understand your point - are you saying that by making it 50+ you ensure open passages only upto ~5 times as large as the narrow passage (253) would be considered equivalent per se?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-17**:
Basically yes, under the assumption that my guess is correct. There might be other motivations.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-19**:
Those are the motivations as far as I have been able to uncover. Note that global_planner has these factors as dynamic parameters.